# Is it possible to trigger alarm based on output of bash command

Tags: monitoring, zabbix, datadog

Is it possible to trigger alarm in zabbix or datadog based on output of bash command. I.e. I have a bash command that returns value and I want to trigger an alarm if value rises above some level.

Answer (score -2):

add bash script as userparameters in zabbix-agent.

Comment: like that?UserParameter=key,BASH_SCRIPT    What would be the key here - the documentation is a bit poor. And how the key will evaluate the number I will get from the script and trigger is bigger then X

Comment: for example: UserParameter=smartctl.temp[*],sudo /usr/sbin/smartctl -x /dev/$1. key - you can come up with

Comment: Can I have it like that - UserParameter=counting[*],grep “blabla” /var/log/applog | wc –l